# Proving $\lim_{n(\in\mathbb{N})\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx} \equiv \sum_0^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$ for all rational $x$

Tags: power-series, exponentiation

I am trying to derive the power series representation for $e^x$ for rational exponents without using Taylor series. Defining $e$ as $$e:=\lim_{n(\in\mathbb{N})\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n,$$
I want to show that $e^x=\left( \lim_{n(\in\mathbb{N})\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \right)^x= \lim_{n(\in\mathbb{N})\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}$ is equivalent to $\sum_0^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$ for all **rational exponents.** Using the ratio test, I know that this power series is convergent for all real (and thus rational) $x$; I just need to prove that it converges to $e^x$.

For $x\in \mathbb{N}$, $nx\in \mathbb{N}$, so I can just use $t=nx$, and use the (regular) binomial theorem to expand $(1+\frac{x}{t})^{t} $ inside the limit and then take it to arrive at the power series. I'm not sure what to do with non-natural exponents however. I know I can use  Newton's Generalized Binomial Theorem, but all proofs of that involve Taylor series or differential equations, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @BrianMoehring If I could just show this property also holds for $x\in \mathbb{Q}^-$, I think the proof would be complete.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tag{1}e=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}\text{.}$$
By induction and Mertens' theorem, we get, for each positive integer $n$,
$$\tag{2}e^n=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{n^k}{k!}\text{.}$$
For
$$e^{n+1}=e^ne=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{n^k}{k!}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\sum^k_{m=0}\frac{n^m}{m!}\frac{1}{(k-m)!}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(n+1)^k}{k!}\text{.}$$
Similarly, for each positive integer $n$, we have
$$\left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(\frac{1}{n})^k}{k!}\right)^n=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}=e\text{,}$$
so that
$$\tag{3}e^{1/n}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(\frac{1}{n})^k}{k!}\text{.}$$
Again, by the theorem about Cauchy product, we have
$$\tag{4}\left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(\frac{m}{n})^k}{k!}\right)^n=e^m$$
for any positive integers $m$, $n$, and
$$\tag{5}e^p\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-p)^k}{k!}=1$$
for any positive rational $p$.
Hence
$$\tag{6}e^p=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{p^k}{k!}$$
for all rational $p$.

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Im a little stumped by the "Cauchy Product". I haven't studied power series formally, but this seems to be a key element of the proof so I guess it's best to leave it until I properly studied power sereis

Comment: The theorem is pretty simple. If you understand limit and series, then you definitely can understand the proof.